# PHP, HTTPS, Form submit

Tags: https

We have recently switched to HTTPS and when submitting one of our forms, Firefox pops up:

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is
>   to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by
>   a third party.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?

After saying Yes, the form submits and the page just reloads, the information isn't actually posting?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have fixed this, I had to amend the form action to https.

Comment: You may want to delete this question if you have solved it, or post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it means:

```
<form action="http://www..."
```

has to be changed to

```
<form action="https://www..."
```

As we are not submitting to a secure URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your form action is posting to http not https

// edit, just saw your comment. sorry.